# Gemstones in the light of Islam

Tags: hadith, sunnah, clothing

In there any related Sunnah or hades about stones that we often wear.can woman wear them?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and the stackexchange model I recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help].

Comment: Is it not enough that the Qur'an often quotes "pearls", "rubies" etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Here is Hadiths gives us some information about  the Holy  Prophet Muhammad Ring;

‘Ali bin Abi Taalib Radiyallahu ‘Anhu says: “Rasulullah  Sallallahu Alayhi Wasallam wore his ring in the right hand”.
Hazrat Hammaad bin Salamah says that he saw Hazrat Abdur Rahman bin Abi Rafe’ wearing a ring on his right hand. He asked him the reason and he replied, “I had seen Hazrat  Abdullah bin Ja’far radiyallahu anhu wearing a ring on his right hand, and he said that he had seen the Prophet of Allah sallallahu alaihe wasallam wear a ring on the right hand.”
It is related from Hazrat Abdullah bin Ja’far radiyallahu anhu from another source (another chain of narrators) that the Prophet of Allah sallallahu alaihe wasallam wore a ring on the right hand.

It shows that wearing ring is sunnah but no one is sure about the stone which was used in the ring of Holy Prophet (PBUH) so we can use any stone in it.But believing that this stone can change our destiny is not good.

It was narrated in Sunan Abi Dawood with a saheeh isnaad from ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her) that she said: “Some jewellery came to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) as a gift from the Negus (the ruler of Abyssinia), as a gift to him. It included a gold ring in which was set an Abyssinian stone. The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) picked it up hesitantly with a stick or with his fingers, then he called Umaamah the daughter of Abu’l-‘Aas and his daughter Zaynab. He said, ‘Adorn yourself with this, O my daughter.’” The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) gave a ring to Umaamah, which was formed from a circle of gold, and said, “Adorn yourself with this.” This indicates that gold formed into a circle is permissible on the basis of this report.

Comment: Please share links or references to the Hadiths you quote. It will help readers validate them for authenticity.

Comment: This doesn't address gemstones as it seems